# Logging via log4net to a TextWriter supplied at runtime

Tags: c#, azure, log4net, message-queue

I have a message handler with the following signature running in Azure:

```
public static void DispatchQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("bq")] string msg,
                                                             TextWriter tw)
```

I'd like to configure log4net to use the provided TextWriter.

If that's not possible generically, I would absolutely settle for a single ILog instance outputting with standard formatting!

---

I ended up doing (something like) the following:

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(name);

var appender = new TextWriterAppender();  

appender.Writer = tw;
appender.Threshold = log4net.Core.Level.Debug;

DynamicPatternLayout layout = new DynamicPatternLayout();
layout.ConversionPattern = "%d [%t] %-5p %m%n";
layout.ActivateOptions();

appender.Layout = layout; 
appender.ActivateOptions();

((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger) log.Logger).AddAppender(appender);
Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
hierarchy.Configured = true;
return log;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Create your own appender class?

Comment: Why are you adding the new appender to a specific ILog instance? Wouldn't it make more sense to add it to the root of the repository (hierarchy) so all ILog instances end up writing to it?